# Integrate a selected music file into video

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, video, mpmusicplayercontroller

I am developing a video recording application and I would like to be able to integrate a music file selected by the user from the iPod library. Please share your inputs as to how I can achieve this requirement. Sample code is helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally succeeded Integrate a selected music file into video

Using AVAssetExportSession we can merge Video and audio together using AVMutableComposition.

Thanks for update all of you!!

//This method merges the audio and video.

```
- (void)mergeAudioAtUrl:(NSURL *)audioUrl withVideoAtUrl:(NSURL *)videoUrl toUrl:(NSURL *)outputUrl
  {

//_imageCaptureCount = [_imagesArray count]*100;

AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:audioUrl options:nil];
AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:videoUrl options:nil];

AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];


if([[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] count])
{
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionCommentaryTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio 
                                                                                        preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

    [compositionCommentaryTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration) 
                                        ofTrack:[[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] 
                                         atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];
}
AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo 
                                                                               preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration) 
                               ofTrack:[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] 
                                atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

[audioAsset release];
[videoAsset release];

AVAssetExportSession* _assetExport = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition 
                                                                      presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];   

NSURL    *exportUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/%@Video.mp4", NSHomeDirectory(),pcNameString]];

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/%@Video.mp4", NSHomeDirectory(),pcNameString]]) 
{
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/%@Video.mp4", NSHomeDirectory(),pcNameString] error:nil];
}

_assetExport.outputFileType = @"com.apple.quicktime-movie"; //com.apple.m4v-video
_assetExport.outputURL = exportUrl;
_assetExport.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;

[_assetExport exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:
 ^(void ) {      
     // your completion code here
    // NSLog(@"completed");

     removeProgresBarFlag = YES;


    /* NSString* savedVideoFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/PC%d.mp4", NSHomeDirectory(),[videosListArray count]];

     if(UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(savedVideoFilePath))
     {
         [[UIApplication sharedApplication]beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
         UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(savedVideoFilePath, self, nil, nil);
         [[UIApplication sharedApplication]endIgnoringInteractionEvents];

     } */


     NSMutableDictionary* videoDetailDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

     NSStringEncoding encoding;
     NSError* error;

     NSString * persistentID;
     NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

     if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:PRESENTSONGS_FILE_PATH])
         persistentID = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:PRESENTSONGS_FILE_PATH usedEncoding:&encoding error:&error];
     else 
         persistentID = @"";

     [videoDetailDict setObject:persistentID forKey:KSong];

     if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:PRESENTIMAGES_FILE])
     {

         NSMutableArray* currentImagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:IMAGESDATA_FILE_PATH];
         NSMutableArray* durationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/videoduration.plist", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
         [videoDetailDict setObject:[durationArray objectAtIndex:[currentImagesArray count]-1] forKey:KfileSize];
         [durationArray release];


         [videoDetailDict setObject:currentImagesArray forKey:KImagesList];
         if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:TEMPVIDEO_FILE_PATH])
         [fileManager removeItemAtPath:TEMPVIDEO_FILE_PATH error:nil];

         NSString* mainPath;

             mainPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/%@File",NSHomeDirectory(),pcNameString];

         if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:mainPath])
             [fileManager removeItemAtPath:mainPath error:nil];

         [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:mainPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];


         for(int i=0;i<[currentImagesArray count];i++)
         {
             [fileManager copyItemAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",PRESENTIMAGES_FILE,[currentImagesArray objectAtIndex:i]] toPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",mainPath,[currentImagesArray objectAtIndex:i]] error:nil];
         }
         [currentImagesArray release];

     }

     if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:KMESSAGE_FILEPATH])
     {
         NSMutableDictionary* currentMessageDictioanry = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:KMESSAGE_FILEPATH];
         [videoDetailDict setObject:currentMessageDictioanry forKey:Kmessage];
         [currentMessageDictioanry release];
     }

     [videoDetailDict setObject:pcNameString forKey:KPostCardName]; //[NSString stringWithFormat:@"PostCard Video%d",[videosListArray count]]
     //[videosListArray insertObject:videoDetailDict atIndex:0];
     [videosListArray addObject:videoDetailDict];
     [videoDetailDict release];
     [videosListArray writeToFile:VIDEOS_FILE_PATH atomically:YES];

 }       
 ];
}
```

Comment: Hi, Can you please help me? I am work on same use case but not able to get video in merging file. I am able to get AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted status for assetSession but not able to see the video. I have checked my video file and it is proper.. also my audio file is proper... but when merging both video is not getting displayed.... Can you tell me what could be the problem??

Comment: Updated my answer, check it!